# Efficient way to index and search thousands of conditions?

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js, conditional-statements

I've been coding a simple chat bot in JavaScript as practice and fun. I hope to build off of it, and refactor it as I go along.

As it is, the search function, which loops every time it reads a new message is inefficient for looking up thousands of conditions.

Here is the code. Each word is an array value and it searches for a matching case.

```
function simpleReactSearch(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv) {
    if (msg[0] === "hooray") {
        switch (msg[1]) {
            case "hi":
            case "hello":
            case "greetings":
            case "howdy":
            case "welcome":
            case "hiya":
            case "hi-ya":
            case "aloha":
                return commonReact("greeting", handle, priv);
            case "ohayou":
            case "morning":
                return commonReact("morning", handle, priv);
            case "bonjour":
            case "konbanwa":
                break;
            case "konnichiwa":
                break;
            case "oyasuminasai":
                break;
            case "goodbye":
            case "seeya":
                break;
            case "sayonara":
                break;
            case "echo":
                pureMsg.splice(0,2);
                return "Echo: "+pureMsg.join(' ');
            case "say":
                pureMsg.splice(0,2);
                return pureMsg.join(' ');
        }       
        switch (msg[1]+" "+msg[2]) {
            case "good morning":
                break;
            case "good afternoon":
                break;
            case "good night":
                break;
            case "good evening":
            case "buenas noches":
                break;
            case "good day":
            case "buenos dias":
                break;
            case "dewa mata":
            case "see ya":
            case "see you":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

I've read that an array lookup is more efficient for this type of search, but even that doesn't seem practical with thousands of conditions in a loop. Yet, would that be best?

I was thinking of storing these cases and conditions in a config file for easy editing, but wouldn't that be even more inefficient?

One way to deal with this I think, is to add a database of sorts. If possible I'd prefer not to go down that road.

Now I can see of one way to make it a little more efficient, and that is to search only certain switch groups if the sentence has the right amount of words or specific words.

**In summary:**

Would it be better to turn switch case groups into arrays, or can Node.js handle arrays and switch statements with about the same efficiency?

Are there other ways to make this more efficient besides basic selective searching?

Comment: Chatbots usually work by splitting up your message and parsing it one word at a time. They don't look at your entire message at once, and then return the predetermined response for the SPECIFIC thing that you wrote. That would be too many cases. Think of a text game like Zork. The way you're doing it "look at object" wouldn't work, but "look object" would.

Comment: @Houseman Yeah, that's what I've done, decomposed the sentence into individual words, and then put that in an array. If the first word is Hooray, the name of the bot, then it knows it's being directly addressed. Then it checks the second word, msg[1] and goes from there. I figured out as I was writing this question that I can make some very selective searches to find the right condition more efficiently. I might be able to remove some useless words from a sentence, such as the the "at" in "look at object".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some maps.

So create the actions you want as functions, func1,func2 etc (use more descriptive names)

then add them to maps like this

```
var map = {
    "hi": func1,
    "hello": func1,
    "test": func2,
    "whatever": func3
}
```

then you can just do

```
if(msg[0] === "hooray") {
    map[msg[1]]();
}
else
{
     map2[msg[0]+" "+msg[1]]();
}
```

Comment: i would recommend a small tweak to that using a 2nd LUT (object) to store the actual functions. this allows simpler repetition of word handlers and the use of JSON to store the config. instead of the word LUT storing the function, it stores a number or letter pointing to a function in a 2nd object/array. You might also save some memory use this way, but the main benefit is shorter code, declaritive config, and  JSON import/export of the config.

Comment: You'd definitely want to use some form of map. If he's really looking at thousands, anything you can do to ensure that it's using a hashmap implementation from the getgo will increase performance.

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: mapMsg1[msg[1]] is not a function.




`function simpleReactSearch(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv) {
if (priv > 0) {
  var mapMsg0 = {
   "hooray": heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv),
   "hellowound": helloWound(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv)
  }
  mapMsg0[msg[0]]();
 }
}`
+
`function heyListen(handle, msg, pureMsg, priv) {
 var mapMsg1 = {
  "hi": commonReact("greeting", handle, priv),
  "hello": commonReact("greeting", handle, priv)
 }
 mapMsg1[msg[1]]();
}`

Comment: Do these maps require a framework, such as jQuery.js or underscore.js? As it is, it's treating the map part of `map2[msg[1]]();` as if it were trying to be a function when the function doesn't exist while it itself is not a function. Does it matter what the map is called? Can it be called `thisIsaMap[msg[1]]();`? Right now I'm running all the code from an html document in Firefox, and plan to use Node.js later.

Comment: the "map" is just a simple javascript object.  JS objects are key value pairs, so they naturally act as map data structures.  And you can call them whatever name you want, as long as you're consistent about it.